# Congregation sings parts of the Shiroh before the reader on the seventh day of Pesach?

Tags: minhag, passover, song-poetry

Is there a recognised minhag for the congregation to sing selected verses from the [“Song at the Sea” (Shiroh) Shmos 15 (1-18)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9876)  before they are read by the reader on the seventh day of Pesach?

Related [How to deal with the parts of the Torah reading that are pre-empted by the congregation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-to-deal-with-the-parts-of-the-torah-reading-that-are-pre-empted-by-the-congr).

Comment: I don't know of this minhag, but there is certainly a minhag to sing the pesukim responsively using the melody for the verses which have shemot.

Comment: Why might you think there is such a Minhag?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Can you source it please? I observed it in a Shul but it was only for a few of the verses that have shemot.

Comment: I saw this at Orach Chaim in NYC.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&pgnum=428