# Why many say "כאלה" during leining?

Tags: halacha, passover

Why do many people say כאלה with the Baal koreh during the leining of pesach? (http://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=31122 confirms what I find to be true across the spectrum of different kinds of shuls all having some people who feel this is a minhag.)

Comment: Is there evidence that people feel it is a religious obligation, or are they simply eager to break the monotony listening to the reader, by joining in with the sudden dramatic change in cancellations?

Comment: I'm not sure I recall this properly, but isn't it an azla without a kadma, so the pause and adjustment is a bit jarring. I have seen people sing along to the random bits of leining they recognize during the whole year. This just seems to be well known. I never thought of it as an actual minhag.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-to-deal-with-the-parts-of-the-torah-reading-that-are-pre-empted-by-the-congr#comment26705_118

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468/2016/4/25

Comment: My bar mitzvah sedra was parashas Pinechas. R' David Willig prepared a tape for me to practice with. In the middle of shishi, there's a pause followed by the only English on the recording. "Here, you pause three seconds to allow the older generation to sing 'ka-ei-ei-leh!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I heard once that this is based on the [Shaarei Efraim 8:24](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41307&st=&pgnum=74&hilite=). The Shaarei Efraim discusses what one does if they skipped the verse beginning with כאלה. Thus there are those who out of concern that it may be missed that say it out loud.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the interesting mekor! So if the Shaarei Efraim would have been speaking about a different pasuk, people would have potentially said that one out loud?